SSH local display window manager
I'm running a program over SSH using either -Y or -X to get the display on my local machine:
ssh -i key user@host -Y -C /path/program
but the results are very poor.

It seems to be using default low-resolution settings or fonts. When run on the remote machine everything looks good.

The remote machine is running CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (can't be changed) and I have tried the ssh command from the latest versions of both Mint and Ubuntu Mate. If run on Windows with Xming it's ok. All machines displays set to 1600x900
Any ideas on how to improve the appearance?
Thanks in advance.

Please [edit] your question and give us (a lot) more context. What are the operating systems involved, both local and remote? What is the exact ssh command (we don't need the IP or hostname, just the options). What is the program? What does it look like? Maybe a screenshot?

Does it work better without the -C? That compresses the data being transferred, so maybe that is causing the problem (doubtful, but worth a try)?

@terdon no only added the -C to try and speed things up. I think its missing a font but don't know how to see what it wants

OK, but please test without it and then add the fact that it makes no difference (assuming it doesn't, which is indeed very likely) to your question. Just to avoid others going down the same rabbit hole. And yes, it does seem like the default monospace font is different on the two machines. I admit I don't really see the problem myself, I had to spend quite a bit of time looking at both your screenshots to note the differences and even then I couldn't figure out which of the two was the "correct" one since both looked so similar and kind of ugly anyway.
